# Generic to assess if a parameter is "instanceof a generic class"

Tags: typescript, generics

I want in a function to determine if the parameter is of a certain class. This is the -non-working- idea:

```
function assertClass<CLASS>(v: any, theClass: CLASS, message: string): v is typeof theClass{

    let is = v instanceof CLASS ;   // err 'CLASS' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
    return assert(is, message);
}
```

What I want to do:

```
let animal: Cat | Dog;
animal= somethingThatCanReturnCatOrDog();
assertClass<Cat>(animal, 'should be a Cat');
```

I tried several combinations with typeof but got more confused ugh!

Comment: Please look at this example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201109#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCAyBBAysg3gXwFBYGYFcA7YAFwEsB7Q6SCAUwCcTZwoAeBFZAPgAoA3AFw1CATwA00EgAs6LWsM6pJAWzpQwAczrCIJBmUKaAlMP7QyMEqIAOdCrimz5UNDmgfoIOiQswAvNDmhnpgxPaOSsgA3J4A9HHQjAzQAORRqdBUIKLQDHS4jFYUNFK2dJIARvi+ltCVdIaa0Pj0ACY0MGBBYCD4dNCy+VieeT74DNS0jCS8lqrqEFp0xtFYGEA    there is no [err 'CLASS' only refers to a type, .....]

Comment: That duplicated question helped partially to solve it but still there's an issue when the constructor of the class is private
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792340/generic-to-assess-if-a-parameter-is-instanceof-a-generic-class-if-constructor